# How to calculate the central factorial moments using raw factorial moments? Please help.

Tags: statistics

How can I calculate the central factorial moments using raw factorial moments? Please let me know if you know the answer to this question.

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: Hey @stubbornAtom I want to calculate the factorial moments of binomial distribution and using these factorial moments , I want to calculate central factorial moments.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question